# Dificuldade em add dados no db usando PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Bom, estou começando os estudos em php e mysql, e estou tendo dificuldades em fazer algo teoricamente simple, que seria um form que envia as informações fornecidas para um db local.
Ao apertar enviar, nada acontece, a tabela do db continua intacta.
Agradeço de antemão o tempo que tiverem pra me ajudar

```
<?php
session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbteste');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password']; //md5 hash passwor security

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES($username, $password, $email)";

        $mysqli->query($sql);

    }
}

?>
    <h1>Register</h1>
<form class="form" action="create-account.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" required/>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password" required/>
    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" value="" placeholder="confirm password" required/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="e-mail" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="createacount" value="create acount">
</form>
```

Comment: Essas variavies:`$username, $password, $email` devem estar entre aspas simples... '$username', '$password', '$email'

Se voce der echo nesse $sql e rodar a query num cliente como heidi e workbench, eles vão te mostrar o erro que está dando

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja um erro na criação do comando SQL, tente usar:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES('".$username."', '."$password."', '".$email."')";
```

Use estes comandos para mostrar os erros caso esteja ocorrendo algum:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Recomendo também que você pesquise um pouco sobre SQL Injection.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Vou ler sobre sim!!

Answer (score 0):

As variáveis PHP em VALUES precisam estar entre aspas simples!

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";

Eu não sei sobre o $_SERVER, eu faço assim:

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,$banco) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, consegui solucionar aqui